# PHP find double digit number before a given word

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to find either a double or single-digit number that appears before a given word that is buried in a long string. For example find the number of children when given as follows:

Derive 12 from:

> blah blah..................12 children............blah blah

or 6 from:

> blah blah......6 children.............blah blah

The following code works for single digit but only returns 2 for the double digit

```
<?php

    $body = ("..blah..blah...6 children....");

    $children_single = explode ("children", $body);
    $num_children  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", substr($children_single[0],-2));
    echo $num_children;

?>
```

How do I adjust this to give both a single or double digit result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current condition is failing because of the space. When you explode the string `12 children`, the first part, `$children_single[0]`, will contain the string `12` (note the space). So, when you use `substr()` on that string, the space will be included and will only capture `2` (with the space).

To avoid that, you can start `substr()` count from the beginning, by using the second parameter, like so:

```
$num_children  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", substr($children_single[0], 0, 2));
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/mlnV2LGQ)

**UPDATE:**

As per your comment, the above version won't work if the word `children` occurs in a long string. In that case, you can use a negative start, as follows:

```
$num_children  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", substr($children_single[0], -3, -1));
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/7ubY1XRI)

Comment: I used the explode to find the word "children" that occurs only once in a very long string. I then use -2 in the substr to count back to the number after finding the word children. Your solution works for the "$children" declaration but does not work when the word children is buried in a larger haystack.